# Increase font-size with CSS creates unwanted indent

Tags: css, text-size

This one has me stumped.

I have plain text, which is generated by Ajax. Then using CSS, specifically to the uniquely tagged class I want to increase the font size.

Here is the line in my CSS

```
#text_li{font-weight:bold;font-size:large;}
```

The result is large text but it then indents the text. Using firebug, adding and removing this parameter, both reduces the font size and removes the indent.

How can I increase the text size without adding an indent?

Edit: I have tried em and pixels, also tested this across Chrome and Firefox.

Edit2: This is CSS specifically for a Wordpress Widget. When I use jsfiddle I can't replicate the problem. So I'm looking in to whether my main theme CSS is somehow interfering.

Edit3: I replicated the issue when I included my Wordpress theme CSS in the markup. So I assume there is a conflict with the two CSS files I'm using. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rVHjv/4/) is the jsfiddle.

Comment: Something else is the issue here http://jsfiddle.net/rVHjv/

Comment: I was just going to say you're doing something wrong as well :)... You certain there isn't a space in there? Some alignment issue, specific font, etc.?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: How do you expect to style plain text in CSS? Or to tag things in plain text with a class? The odds are that you actually have some HTML or XML involved, so please show the HTML, preferably together with a jsfiddle that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: See my edit 2. Is it possible my Wordpress theme is imparting some other CSS to this plugin?

Comment: how about setting font-size:0 to the parent element

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rVHjv/4/) is the jsfiddle. I have narrowed it down to my Theme CSS, which is somehow introducing the indent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this classs

```
.samsonginfo_widget_info
{
   margin-left:0;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rVHjv/5/)**

Comment: Thanks:) That worked. With regard to best practice, what should I be doing moving forward to avoid CSS conflicts like this?

Comment: Use inspect element in chrome and take a look what's causing the problem (that's what i did)

Answer (score 0):

What about addding margin and padding as zero?

```
#text_li{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:large;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

If this doesn't work, please post a jsfiddle.

Comment: margin and padding has nothing to do with this

Comment: Perhaps comments are better suited for shooting in the dark?

Comment: Adding `padding:0` does nothing. But `margin:0;` has the opposite effect and justifies the text too far left, closer than the rest of the items in the slightly indented list. I'll try to replicate in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could just play with the text indent of the element:

```
text-indent: -0.05em;
```

I tried with this value and works good to me.